# Doing a simple search

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a simple search, would the following query be correct?

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE'$searchquery' AND description LIKE'$searchquery'");
```

EDIT:

`LIKE '$searchquery;` this part needed a space, it turns out it was a syntax issue. I am quite intrigued by doing it the second way. As suggested by @yes123.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(name,description) AGAINST ('$searchQuery')
```

I do this and I get:

`Warning: mysql_numrows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/search.php on line 62`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For searching purpouse you should use a FULL TEXT index. At that point your query becomes something like:

```
[...] WHERE MATCH(col1,col2) AGAINST ('your search') [...]
```

And please use PDO

Comment: replace col with my column I presume?

Comment: I do not have the db prepared for fulltext I know this for future, I will implement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the syntax is correct, only problem seems to be is with spaces after LIKE, hence try
`SELECT * FROM products WHERE NAME LIKE '$searchquery' AND description LIKE '$searchquery';`

Answer (score 1):

That would be correct, however, you need to put a space between `LIKE` and `'$searchquery'` in both places.